# How to apply assembly reference when using only a text editor?

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating an application and I have decided to separate bits of code onto different files. However I encountered a problem where the C-SHARP Compiler prints

> The type or namespace name '*' could not be found
>
> (Are you a missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

And no, I am not missing a using directive because both files have the same namespace. However an assembly reference intrigues me. How do i create an assembly reference when i am only using a text editor and a command prompt?

---

**Extra Detail(s)**:

1. The folder that contains my application, as of now will contain an exe and a dll file.
2. The error occurs in the exe file, and the missing type/namespace is in the dll file.
3. The reason why i am using a text editor is because there is too much to look at in an IDE, but in a text editor you can only see open files and text, so it seems easier for me to code in a text editor.
4. I use the C-Sharp Compiler that the .NET Framework supplies me or CSC in Command Prompt.
5. I am actually using Visual Studio Code, which feels more like a text editor than an IDE. Therefore I like it, because it fulfills Extra Detail No. 3.

---

**Here's the initialization code:**

```
using System;
namespace Bytewar {
    class Initialize {
        Player main = new Player("Main");
        Player com1 = new Player("Com1");
        Player com2 = new Player("Com2");
    }
}
```

**The missing type or namespace:**

```
namespace Bytewar {
    public class Player {
        // I have erased the code here. Just focus on the missing type problem.
    }
}
```

**And the compiler's code:**

```
@echo off
csc /t:library player.cs
csc bytewar.cs
pause
```

Comment: running `csc /?` should give you the info.

Comment: you are using normal solution-projects setup with .sln and .csproj files, right?

Comment: no I don't have a file with an extension type of .sln and .csproj, only .cs, also i found an option in csc /? that intrigues me _/lib:<file list>_ I don't know how to use that though.

Comment: how do you compile your assembly?

Comment: with .Net framework's C-Sharp Compiler or CSC in a command prompt

Comment: Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ds95cz0.aspx

Comment: or [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f73ea717-0bad-4335-8a35-130847eae231/how-to-specify-dll-library-path-in-csc-command-line?forum=csharplanguage)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, I have fixed my problem by changing my compiler's code on line 3 to `csc /reference:player.dll bytewar.cs`

Comment: please post it as an answer and accept it (you can, and should, answer your own questions)

Comment: ok, i will try that slawekwin. I did not know answering your own questions was legal lol

Comment: Re Extra Details No 3 - Have you tried running Visual Studio in Full Screen mode?

Comment: sgmoore, how would running visual studio in FULL SCREEN help fix my problem? can someone please close this thread?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by changing the compiler's code on line 3 from `csc bytewar.cs` to `csc /reference:player.dll bytewar.cs`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you do not give enough information's to reproduce your problem. How are we supposed to help you ?

There are two free IDE that you could use instead of a text editor :

- SharpDevelop
- visual studio community edition

Comment: I have explained why I don't like to use an IDE. I'll be adding in more details.